# Stackmob console logs definition?

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I am getting below log errors on stackmob console but dont know what is wrong happening ?

WARN    Push Service
No push tokens found while pushing to 1 tokens with payload {"alert":"New alert(s) available","badge":"1","type":"1"}.

Comment: Please include the code you are using to send the notification.

Comment: Client side or Backend ?

Comment: Well, if you get this error in the Back-end (as I assume), then you should include the Back-end code. I assume the notification doesn't reach the device.

Comment: The above error logs are produced from the stackmob .....